# How to invoke Ctrl+Shift+j when running Laravel Dusk to open DevTools in the Console tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, laravel-dusk

I know Chrome with DevTools opened can be executed using `chrome.exe --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`. However, it doesn't open on the Console tab.

There is a keyboard shortcut to do just this: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `j`.

**How can this be achieved in [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#using-the-keyboard)** (which uses Facebook's WebDriver under the hood)?

I have tried:

```
$browser->driver
        ->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('body'))
        ->sendKeys([WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, 'a']) // Select all - WORKS
        ->sendKeys([WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, WebDriverKeys::SHIFT, 'j']) // Open DevTools in Console tab - DOES NOT WORK
        ->sendKeys([WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, 'l']); // Clear Console - DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: Why do you want to open the console tab?

Comment: To see where JavaScript issues occur as Laravel Dusk tests are performed. I know you get the console output after each Dusk execution (if an error has occurred) but it is helpful to watch as issues occur. I also know you can interact with Chrome during testing and switch to the console tab yourself but it would be good to automate it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Do you have an explanation as to why?

Comment: I guess Chrome only supports the keyboard shortcuts that interact with the website itself.

Comment: Are you seeking to then open Chrome DevTools to get something specific or is it just the convenience of opening DevTools to inspect the page?

Comment: Purely convenience in order to spot issues more readily